# A Verification using Schwarz inequality

Tags: functional-analysis, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations

I'm having difficulty following this reasoning:
[image]

1. How is equality being used in the Schwarz inequality? I'm getting lost between using it between the usual dot product and the inner product between $L^2$ spaces ($\nabla u_0 \in L^2$).
2. How are they concluding that $u_0(r \xi) = r u_0(\xi)$ (i.e. $u_0$ is 1-homogeneous).

Comment: Btw, this is the Schwarz with no "t" in his name...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author is applying the Schwarz inequality to the functions $f(r)=1$ and $g(r)=\nabla u_0(r\xi)\cdot\xi$ on the interval $[0,t]$. We have
$$\left(\int_0^t f(r)g(r)\,dt\right)^2 \le \int_0^t f(r)^2\,dr \int_0^t g(r)^2\,dr,$$
and equality holds iff $g$ is a scalar multiple of $f$, i.e., $g$ is a constant function of $r$.

Comment: thanks! almost there -- I'm not seeing how $g(r) = C$ implies homogeneity though

Comment: Remember the chain rule: $C = \nabla u_0(r\xi)\cdot\xi = \frac d{dr}u_0(r\xi) \implies u_0(r\xi) = Cr\ (+C')$.